# Angular: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

Tags: angular

My HTML is giving the following error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 0: { label: string; color: string; }; 1: { label: string; color: string; }; 2: { label: string; color: string; }; 3: { label: string; color: string; }; 4: { label: string; color: string; }; }'.ngtsc(7053)

Here is the HTML where the error occurs:

```
<p-tag
[value]="orderStatus[order.status].label"
[severity]="orderStatus[order.status].color"
>
</p-tag>
```

This portion specifically is giving the said error: `"orderStatus[order.status]"`

Here is the TS file where I have defined orderStatus:

```
 const ORDER_STATUS = {
  0: {
    label: 'Pending',
    color: 'primary'
  },
  1: {
    label: 'Processed',
    color: 'warning'
  },
  2: {
    label: 'Shipped',
    color: 'warning'
  },
  3: {
    label: 'Delivered',
    color: 'success'
  },
  4: {
    label: 'Failed',
    color: 'danger'
  }
};

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-orders-list',
  templateUrl: './order-list.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class OrdersListComponent implements OnInit 
{
...
  orderStatus = ORDER_STATUS;
... 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `order.status` has type `any`, but you didn't post the `order` and its type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define type for your order status index key as `number`.

E.g:

```
interface IOrderStatus {
  [key: number]: {
    label: string;
    color: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label') on this line: [value]="orderStatus[order.status].label"

Comment: Try this: `<p-tag [value]="orderStatus[order.status]?.label [severity]="orderStatus[order.status]?.color"></p-tag>`

Comment: Thank you again Amit, but now I am getting an an error on [value] called Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: You should not render p-tag if the value is undefined.
`<p-tag *ngIf="orderStatus[order.status]" [value]="orderStatus[order.status].label [severity]="orderStatus[order.status].color"></p-tag>`

Comment: Thanks Amir. No error but now order status has gone blank.

Answer (score 1):

define the types for your object like

```
interface OrderStatus {
  label: string;
  color: string;
}

interface OrderStatuses {
  [key: number]: OrderStatus;
}
```

and use these type for you data

```
const ORDER_STATUS: OrderStatuses = {
  0: {
    label: 'Pending',
    color: 'primary'
  },
  1: {
    label: 'Processed',
    color: 'warning'
  },
  2: {
    label: 'Shipped',
    color: 'warning'
  },
  3: {
    label: 'Delivered',
    color: 'success'
  },
  4: {
    label: 'Failed',
    color: 'danger'
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the error, but now I have a new error ROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label')

Comment: Please check if your object for that particular index is defined or not before accessing it.